# How to declare parameters/variables indexed by a sub-set within an array of sets in Pyomo?

Tags: arrays, linear-programming, variable-declaration, pyomo

In Pyomo, one can declare an array of sets (a set of sets or sub-sets indexed by another set) with the following command (according to documentation):

```
model.A=Set()
model.B=Set()
model.C=Set(model.B, within=model.A)
```

I wonder how I can declare a variable or a parameter to be indexed by one of the (sub-)sets in the array of sets in an abstract model? For example, how can I declare a parameter 'model.d' that is indexed by both model.B and model.C[model.B] where each element in model.B identify a sub-set of model.A?

When I declare it like this:

```
model.d=Param(model.B, model.C[model.B])
```

I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: Error retrieving component C[B]: The component has not been constructed.
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, simply `model.d=Param(model.B, model.C)` may be what you're looking for.

It also looks like you are using `AbstractModel`. I know a lot of the examples use abstract models, but often `ConcreteModel` behavior is more intuitive for someone starting out. Does your use case involve solving the same model structure multiple times with different data?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am familiar with abstract models and have been using AMPL before.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I come from a GAMS background, hence the difference in perspective. Did the adjustment work for you, though?

Comment: I see, I prefer the "abstract" approach to keep the model structure and the data input separate. 

I solved it differently: I declared a two dimensional set that contains tuples (i,j). The first index, i, refers to the indexing set (model.B) and the second index, j, refers to the element of the sub-set (j in model.C[i]).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I declared a two dimensional set that contains tuples (i,j) instead of indexing a set. The first index, i, refers to the indexing set (model.B) and the second index, j, refers to the element of the sub-set (j in model.C[i]).

My code is therefore:

```
model.A = Set()
model.B = Set()
model.C = Set(dimen=2)

model.d = param(model.C)
```

I load the data for model.C as a set_array, i.e. a matrix with + and -. The parameter model.d is now indexed over two sets: model.B and a sub-set of model.A:

```
data.load(filename='Sets.xlsx',range='C',using='xlsx',format="set_array", set=model.C)
```

Where the loaded table looks something like this:

```
SetC   b1   b2   b3   b4
a1      +    -    -    +
a2      +    +    +    -
a3      -    +    +    +
```